# How to add drop-down country list in yii?

Tags: php, yii

I am new to Yii and frankly new to Object oriented php also. I am trying to learn this. Just needed some help.

Now i create a New customer table for customer details, here have a country field, I need  create a drop-down list of countries.
Here i use this code

```
             <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'country'); ?>
            <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'country',Lookup::country()); ?>
            <?php echo $form->error($model,'country'); ?>
```

but the error show on

```
include(Lookup.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

So here how can i create the Lookup.php file
Please if anyone could help me with this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a Lookup.php file? If you have autoloading set in your config file set to `'import'=>array(
        'application.models.*',
        'application.components.*',
    ),` then you can put Lookup.php file in one of those folders. The results of that could be the result of a [listData](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#listData-detail) output or could simply be an associative array of 'value'=>'label'.